# DAG successfully finished - difference between dark green vs light green circles

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, airflow

What's the difference between dark green (surrounded by the black line) & light green circle on DAG successful run (see attached snapshot where last three circles are light green while rest are dark green.)

[DAG Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUEBK.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DAGs/tasks with a black border are scheduled runs, whereas the non-bordered DAGs/tasks are manually triggered, i.e. by airflow trigger_dag.

It is documented here:
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html#task-lifecycle

[image]

Comment: Seems like intuitively there should be something about that here. 
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ui.html

Comment: Thanks @kaxil for quick reply.